# Maintaining IQueryable between page lifecycles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5/Entity Framework website where the site user may build up complex queries, sort/filter them etc on a group of users/items etc. However, I need a way to maintain the query "state" between page cycles, send them to other pages for further manipulation etc. Here are some approaches that I've considered:

- Convert all the query result to IEnumerable (or list): this would be extremely inefficient as I need to load and enumerate ALL the users of the list in memory, where I may need only a very small subset of them (I am using pagination).
- Convert the query to raw SQL using `ToString` method. However, this way, while I can paginate and query, I still lose the ability to edit the query.
- Leave the `IQueryable` object as it is, somewhere in memory, to use it in the next page/query etc.. This one, in addition to being a very bad/inefficient practice, would render to object unusable due to the fact that IQueryable is returned within the database context (`DbContext`), thus will be invalid after the context is disposed.

What is the best practice of maintaining the "state" of a query object between page lifecycles? Both server side and client side solutions are accepted, as long as they conform my requirements (not loading the whole database in memory, being able to modify the query after execution, pagination, sorting...)

Comment: Separate the query and its [specifications](http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/09/11/using-the-specification-pattern-for-querying/). You can store the specifications and re-apply them to the query body.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you are now 'editing' the IQueryable. Since you cannot undo parts 'inside' the IQueryable this sounds impossible to me.

IMHO, you need to separate the definition of the query and the execution of the query.

The definition I would store in a custom solution. It can be anything, define some class to store the user defined query, it will probably contain a collection of some sort, to represent in-memory what the user is seeing on the view.

To execute the query you will have to convert the user defined query into a real query that you can execute on the database. It can be raw SQL, but an IQueryable is just as good.

If you make the user defined query serializable, which should not be a problem since you are defining it yourself, you can simple save the serialized 'state' in the page, a hidden field for example.

You also do not actually need an IQueryable object until you want to execute the query.

Comment: By 'editing', I mean representing a query and in another page, changing part of the query (and if the latter is less restrictive, obviously, re-roundtrip to the database)